# C and MATLAB: Create empty array in C calls Matlab function to fill it ends in error

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, segmentation-fault

This is the problem:

I have a C code that creates an array `nRows x 2`, called `InitialArray` filled with random numbers. Then I split that array into two parts, that is the first column is called `xProcess` and the second column of the array is `yProcess`. 
The goal is to pass these variables I created (`xProcess` and `yProcess`) to Matlab and there a Matlab function based on probabilities rules will put `NaN` in some of the elements of `xProcess` and `yProcess`, and will fill empty arrays called `xC` and `yC` with the values of `xProcess` and `yProcess` before turning to `NaN`. 
Finally, the C code gets all four arrays back again, perform some operations on them and send them again to Matlab. This process is repeated for a number of time steps.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
int main ( void ){

Engine *ep;
if (!(ep = engOpen(""))) {

    fprintf(stderr, "\nCan't start MATLAB engine\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

mxArray *xProcess = NULL;
mxArray *yProcess = NULL;    
mxArray *xC = NULL;
mxArray *yC = NULL;

int timeStep;
int numberProcess = 4e6;
int numberC = 0;
```

So far I created the mxArray, and the number of random numbers that will be stored in `xProcess` and `yProcess`. Now comes the loop.

```
for (timeStep=0 ; timeStep<numberTimeSteps ; timeStep++){

double *arrayTempxProcess;
arrayTempxProcess = (double *)calloc(numberProcess, sizeof(double)); 
double *arrayTempyProcess;
arrayTempyProcess = (double *)calloc(numberProcess, sizeof(double));   

double *arrayTempxC;
arrayTempxC=(double *)calloc(numberC, sizeof(double)); 
double *arrayTempyC;
arrayTempyC=(double *)calloc(numberC, sizeof(double)); 

xProcess = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(numberProcess, 1, mxREAL); 
yProcess = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(numberProcess, 1, mxREAL);

xC = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(numberC, 1, mxREAL); 
yC = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(numberC, 1, mxREAL);

memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(yProcess), (void *)arrayTempyProcess, numberProcess*sizeof(double));
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(xProcess), (void *)arrayTempxProcess, numberProcess*sizeof(double));
```

As you see `xC` and `yC` I create them as empty. I believe this is equivalent to `xC = []` and `yC = []` in Matlab. And the `arrayTempyProcess` and `arrayTempxProcess` are temporal arrays that each of them gets a column of `InitialArray`.

```
if(timeStep>0){
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(yC), (void *)arrayTempyC,(numberC)*sizeof(double));
memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(xC), (void *)arrayTempxC, (numberC)*sizeof(double)); 

}
```

Now I send them to Matlab

```
engPutVariable(ep, "xProcess", xProcess);
engPutVariable(ep, "yProcess", yProcess);
engPutVariable(ep, "xC", xC);
engPutVariable(ep, "yC", yC);


free(arrayTempxProcess);
free(arrayTempyProcess);
free(arrayTempxC);
free(arrayTempyC);
```

Now the Matlab function puts `NaN` in `xProcess` and `yProcess`, and fills `xC` and `yC`.

```
printf("Entering MATLAB \n");
engEvalString(ep, "[xProcess,yProcess,xC, yC] = my_matlab_function(xProcess,yProcess,xC, yC);"); 
printf("Leaving MATLAB \n");
```

Now comes trouble... Now I am trying to get the results... but the function `mxGetM(xC)` produces a segmentation fault in the first time step that I don't understand.

```
xC = engGetVariable(ep,"xC"); 
int mRowsC = mxGetM(xC);


double *XC = NULL;
XC = (double *)malloc (mRowsC*sizeof(double) );
memcpy(XC, mxGetData(xC),mRowsC*sizeof(double));


yC = engGetVariable(ep,"yC");
double *YC = NULL;
YC = (double *)malloc (mmy*sizeof(double) );
memcpy(YC, mxGetData(yC),mmy*sizeof(double));


xProcess = engGetVariable(ep,"xProcess"); 
int mRowsProcess = mxGetM(xProcess);


double *XPROCESS = NULL;
XPROCESS = (double *)malloc (mRowsProcess*sizeof(double) );
memcpy(XPROCESS, mxGetData(xPROCESS),mRowsProcess*sizeof(double));


yProcess = engGetVariable(ep,"yProcess");

double *YPROCESS = NULL;
PROCESS = (double *)malloc (mRowsProcess*sizeof(double) );
memcpy(YPROCESS, mxGetData(yProcess),mRowsProcess*sizeof(double));



numberC = mRowsC;

mxDestroyArray(xProcess);
mxDestroyArray(yProcess);
mxDestroyArray(xC);
mxDestroyArray(yC);
free(XPROCESS);
free(YPROCESS);
free(XC);
free(YC);
}
}
```

I have tried to reduce the number of elements in `xProcess` and `yProcess` but I get the segmentation fault at some point later than the first time step.
The weird thing about this, is that I also tried to save the results in Matlab after `printf("Leaving MATLAB \n");` but it didn't work out. It saved nothing.

I'm new coupling C and Matlab, so my code might be entirely wrong, but is there any limits in which C cannot be coupled with Matlab functions?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The question title says that the issue is about creating empty arrays. Have you done any tests that narrows it down to that problem or is it a guess? also, there is a typo `memcpy(XC, mxGetData(xC),mRowsProcess*sizeof(double));` that should be `memcpy(XPROCESS, mxGetData(xProcess),mRowsProcess*sizeof(double));`

Comment: I have done tests in order to get which line of the code causes the segmentation fault in C. And I narrowed it down to the `mxGetM(xC)` line. When I don't fill `xC` in Matlab I don't get any errors. So my question is more if this is the proper way to fill an empty array in a C code calling a Matlab function.

Comment: xC is created in C, then passed to the Matlab engine. What gets out of that may be totally unrelated to what gets in (code should still work with separate variables `xC_in` and `xC_out`). Actually, you could have a Matlab function that does not take any argument and still returns some variable xC. Have you examined what actually gets in the Matlab function? You could use `engEvalString(ep, "save('dump_input.mat','xProcess','yProcess','xC','yC');");` to check what actually gets into the Matlab function (and another one just after to dump the output). Or do that from within the Matlab function.

Comment: `engGetVariable` will return a NULL pointer in case of failure, which would be a cause for the seg fault with `mxGetM`. You should test that. The variables should exist in Matlab engine workspace regardless of your Matlab function success or failure, though, since they have the same name as the input variables. That is, as long as the calls to `engPutVariable` succeeded (i.e. returned 0). You should test that too. Replace `engPutVariable(ep,"xC",xC)` with `if(engPutVariable(ep,"xC",xC)) {printf('Error putting xC\n');fflush(stdout);}`

Comment: You nailed it! But I still don’t know what is failing. So I saved the input before sending it to Matlab and everything is right. However, saving the output coming from Matlab function saved nothing. Moreover I added a condition if xC is NULL and this condition is met! So clearly what is failing is the line ‘engEvalString(ep,”[xProcess,yProcess,xC,yC] = my_matlab_function(xProcess,yProcess,xC,yC);”);’. But I don’t get it. How is it possible to fail? If I have an error in my_matlab_function this will appear on screen as an error in Matlab. Any guess?

Comment: @S.Perez: Did you try evaluating an obviously wrong statement, see if you can see the error message? It looks like it is possible to turn off output buffering, meaning you wouldn't see any error messages.